# .htaccess redirect does not working well

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect main domain "example.com" to to subdirectory "sub" with .htaccess. I have .htaccess file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub/index.php [L]
```

and it works ok if I enter example.com or www.example.com in address bar in web browser, but if I enter example.com/index.php or www.example.com/index.php that's not working and it goes to primary folder, not in subfolder sub.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Also, you can use [this for testing your htaccess](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you set up your redirect in the index.php file?  Your .htaccess file doesn't have a condition for that.  Since you are hitting the page directly.

As per my comment below, put this into your index.php page:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/sub/index.php");
die();
```

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: It looks like you are trying to intercept connections to your root and send them to "/sub/index.php".  But it's not working when someone enters at "index.php".  That's because the .htaccess won't do anything in that case.  You need to put your redirect inside THAT file.

Comment: I don't want to redirection is visible at address bar and if I redirect it in php file with header() function it is visible. But if it's true that durbnpoisn sad, than that is not possible to do :(